Executing Python Scripts Using "runpy"
I'm toying around with the "runpy" command in python. I'm trying to have Test.py execute Test2.py, but to grant Test2.py access to a variable from Test.py. However, for some strange reason, the "runpy" line seems to be executing Test2.py twice.
When I execute Test.py, my terminal prints "20" twice (that is, as though two separate print commands were issued). If I add a second print command to Test2.py, it then prints four times. It seems like Test2.py is being executed twice by the runpy command.
Script Test.py
import runpy
x = 20
runpy.run_path(path_name="Test2.py")

Script Test2.py
from Test import x
print(x)

P.S. It seems like most programmers don't like this approach, as they seem to prefer keeping all code in a single script, and then just segregating functionality by functions and classes and whatnot. Nevertheless, I'd like to understand what's happening here.
